# Spark aggregation in PySpark, if possible without incurring anymore shuffling operation

Tags: python, apache-spark, aggregation

Is there a way I can covert my df in pyspark which looks like as,

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ['Naman', True,200],
    ['Jason', True,100],
    ['Jason', False,200],
    ['Omar', True,100],
    ['Omar', False,200],
    ['Omar', True,200],
    ['Naman', False,200]
]).toDF(('emp_name', 'class','score'))

df.show()
```

To something like if possible without groupby, However, its already aggregated at unique class and emp_name level, its just i want to create an extra column and reduce emp_name row to unique level.

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|emp_name|class1Score|class2Score|
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   Naman|        200|        200|
|   Jason|        100|        200|
|    Omar|        200|        200|
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless data is already partitioned by `emp_name` (and in your case it isn't, and partitioning as such would require as shuffle) or data is loaded from a table bucketed by `emp_name` (same as before it isn't) reshaping data to the desired format, for example with pivot

```
df.groupBy("emp_name").pivot("class", [True, False]).sum()
```

will require a shuffle.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there is atleast a shuffle required. I cant partition it by emp_name as it will increase number of tasks to many which again is at some point overhead. Thanks for the response.